# Reducer independent incremental Number

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I am trying to port a SAS program into Hive and though I understand it is not the ideal way to go, I am short on time and am afraid will have to live with this for now.

This SAS code below is what I am running into trouble with:

```
if first.CustNo then do;
Call_No=0;
Call_No+1;
Cumm_Call_No+1;
Acct_Switch = 0;
end;

if first.AcctNo then do;
Acct_Switch +1;
Call_ID=0;
Call_ID+1;
if Acct_Switch >1 then do;
Call_Diff=INTCK('second',PrevEnd,NewEnd);
if Call_Diff >1800 then do;
Call_No+1;
Cumm_Call_No+1;
end;
end;
end;

Call_Diff=INTCK('second',PrevEnd,NewEnd);
if Call_Diff >1800 then Call_ID+1;
PrevEnd=0;
PrevEnd+NewEnd;
end;
```

The above code is part of a macro which loops through a log file and spits out the output basis the business logic.

The problem is with the assignment of Call_No and Cumm_Call_No variables. The logic says that once the time difference exceed 30 mins, the code will increment these variables by 1 each and dump the output in a new row even if the CustID and AcctNo remains the same.

However, I need help with this as Hive will throw the data across Reducers each running the code independently and generating their own values for Call_No and Cumm_Call_No. Due to the size of the logs, its highly likely that rows for the same CustID and/or AcctNo will be spread across Reducers.

Does someone have any theories or better yet any solutions on handling such a scenario?

Regards

Capt'n

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your query. If you use the group by clause on CustID and AcctNo then all the rows corresponding to the same CustID and AcctNo will go to the same reducer. That is guaranteed.

For the counters you can use a UDAF to achieve the functionality.